# Enter the same value into multiple cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to enter a same value into multiple cells.
What is the quickest way? (I have tried selecting the cells, typing a value, and pressing Enter.)

Comment: You can mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the cells.
2. Type the value.
3. Press Ctrl-Enter instead of Enter.
   All selected cells will be filled with the value you typed.